Excel adding @ to formulas generated by VBA and causing them to fail
I have this formula being generated in VBA
MyFormula = "=TEXTJOIN(" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Keywords.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & "," & "RC" & ColumnNumber & "))," & Keywords.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))"

which results in this formula being generated in the cell
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(@Sheet3!$A$1:$A$749,$A2)),Sheet3!$A$1:$A$749,""))

My issue is that Excel is automatically adding an @ before the first range (but not the second) which causes the formula to not work.
I can find this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34 explaining that Excel is adding these @s when it thinks it is appropriate but not exactly when it does it or how to stop it doing it. If I just paste the formula it does not add the @ there.
Any suggestions on how to fix this? I can find lots asking why it is happening but nothing on how to fix it. Thanks

When you assign the formula to a range use .Formula2 not .Formula

Great, that has solved it. I was using .FormulaR1C1 but obviously that didn't work.

Posting the answer from the comments so the question can be closed:

When you assign the formula to a range use .Formula2 not .Formula - Scott Craner

For more information, see the Microsoft support page on Formula vs. Formula2.
(Archive version in case of link rot.)
